# problem with using struct as std::map key

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, std

my code is like this:

```
struct Info
{
    string name;
    int score;
    bool operator< (const Info &x) const
    {
        return score < x.score;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Info a, b;
    a.name = "eric";
    a.score = 90;
    b.name = "cat";
    b.score = 85;

    map<Info, int> m;
    m[a] = 1;
    m[b] = 2;

    map<Info, int>::iterator it;
    for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->first.name << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

it prints out "cat" and "eric", as expected.  but how ever, when I modify it to （make a.score and b.score the same）

```
Info a, b;
a.name = "eric";
a.score = 90;
b.name = "cat";
b.score = 90;
```

It prints out "eric" only, there's only one element in the whole map.

question: does std::map think they are the same key?   how do I make std::map think they are not the same key? I tried operator==, but not working.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same key because your custom comparator uses the score as the key. Try this instead

```
bool operator< (const Info &x) const
{
    return name < x.name;
}
```

If you want the name to be the key but the map to be sorted on the score, then I'm afraid you are out of luck, because maps are sorted on the key by definition. You'll have to pick another data structure or another algorithm.

Comment: I want to use both name and score as key,  I think I've solved it by using                         “ if (score == x.score)   return name < x.name;     else return score < x.score;”

Comment: No, that's an invalid comparison function because it doesn't impose a strict weak ordering. Try this version `return score < x.score || (score == x.score && name < x.name); }`

Comment: so what is the mechanics inside std::map?   How does std::map decide if they are the same or not?    I've only provided operator<().    Does map do  a < b and b < a, then found out they are both true, then think a and b are the same key?

Comment: @BunsenBurner Exactly, NO, correction, if both are **false** they are the same key.

Comment: PS https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html, you must have a strict weak ordering or your code will crash (eventually).